# DS.FixtureAdapter is undefined althogh i have added ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
App.PersonAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
TypeError: DS.FixtureAdapter is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`FixtureAdapter` was removed from ember.](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/05/ember-data-1-0-beta-19-released.html#toc_fixture-adapter-removed)

Check out [mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com) for current ember versions.

Comment: please be specific ,I have spend about two days on it but unable to solve this issue?

Comment: How could I be more specific? The `FixtureAdapter` is not longer part of ember-data. This is normal. Don't use it. If you really want to use it there is an [addon](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-data-fixture-adapter), but its not really maintained.

Comment: I am using it in asp.net mvc. when i am ruining "$ ember install ember-cli-mirage" in console manager it gives me error.

Comment: This is a `ember-cli` addon. I strongly recommend you to consider using `ember-cli` for your fronted because only this way you can profit from the ecosystem and use all the plugins. However you *could* just checkout the source code of the plugin and hack it into your own build pipeline, but you really shouldn't. Also *dont* use the fixture adapter!